# Basis of Subspace Confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Find a basis in the subspace $U = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$ of the space $\mathbb R^3$. Surely they mean $.^3\mathbb R$?

I form the matrix with these vectors as columns: $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & -1 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and then reduced to echelon form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

This means the basis is $U = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: What is $^3\Bbb R$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The set of column vectors with $3$ real entries

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: There is no such thing as **the** basis. What you have found is **a** basis (there exists plenty of other bases of the same space.)

Comment: @Digitallis Yes I agree.